# Vuejs searchbar filter returns no result

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter, vue-component

Today I started playing around with VUEjs for the first time, so I tried to get data out from an URL with JSON. This worked perfectly fine, but I wanted more by adding a search bar. I've watched some tutorials online and I did the same as they did, but it didn't worked out very well for me. After adding filter() to my code I couldn't see anything on my screen. I'm now stuck and don't know what I did wrong in my code.

If I write for example "Bitcoin", I want to get the symbol, name and price back.

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="search coin">

   <ul>
       <li v-for="coin in filteredCoins">
           {{ coin.symbol }} {{ coin.name }} {{ coin.quotes['USD']['price']}}
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data: [],
        search: ''
    },
    computed: {
        filteredCoins: function() {
            return this.data.filter((coin) => {
                return coin.title.match(this.search);
            });
        }
    },
    created () {
        fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.data = json.data
            })
    }
})
</script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEwJMy)

Comment: Something [like this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JZzRXB?editors=1010).  As @BillCriswell mentions, your response data is not an array. Also, there is no `title` property on the values.

Answer (score 2):

`json.data` is an object, not an array, so you can't use `filter` on it. You'd need to translate that object to an array to filter it. You can do something like what Bert suggests in his codepen.

```
computed: {
  filteredCoins () {
    return Object.values(this.data).filter(coin => coin.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()))
  },
},
```